# Database References on Deploy

Tags: azure, azure-devops, sql-server-data-tools

I have (several) database project in a solution. In one I have a referesnce to a dacpac (this is ACTUALLY a copy of one of the main databases as we take a SQL snapshot at end of day and some code needs to reference this (DBANME_Daily) rather that DBNAME).
now this builds correctly, the code with SELECT * FROM DBNAME_DAILY.schema.table all compiles and builds with no error.
ON deployment however I get the unresolved reference to DBNAME_DAILY.schema.table

Comment: Are you deploying the DACPAC as a task? The error will be because the database name is not part of the schema, so `SELECT * FROM schema.table` would work and the database name being set in the context of the deployment task. The database name would usually be passed in as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a dacpac for that database as a reference, using variables for the database.  Should be different database, different names.  You'd then use that variable in your code and you'd pass in the variable name for your build/publish tasks depending on the environment.

This is a little older article, but still pretty accurate:
http://schottsql.com/2012/10/31/ssdt-external-database-references/

You can tweak that a little bit using a variable for the database name. When I wrote this, it was mostly just a different database with the same name across environments. For your case, you'd just use the DB variable.  Then replace your "DBName.schema." with "[$DBNameVariable].schema."  (or something similar)

Answer (score 0):

Sorted, my mistake was the dacpac reference would only allow the project to BUILD. For deployment the database DBNAME_DAILY MUST EXIST. 
Lesson Learnt.